# Concatenating multiple rows from same column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a line of SQL that results in 2 rows of 1 cell coming back:

```
SELECT ATTR_VAL FROM [NDC_ATTR] where item_id = 185836 and field_id IN (144,225)
```

Results:

```
1 H400

2 TESTTEXT
```

I am trying to concatenate them together so they look like this 'TESTTEXT[H400]':

```
select concat (
        [NDC_ATTR],
        ' ',
        [NDC_ATTR]
        ) as newColumn
where item_id = 185836
    and field_id in (144, 225)
```

However, I am getting a bunch of errors saying that the column names are wrong.

I think this is because both cells come from the same column.

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

Comment: Your table doesn't have those columns, so I'm just not following the relationship between your query and what you want to do.

Comment: are you trying to concat tables or... where is your `from`?

Comment: look at: http://stackoverflow.com/a/545672/7187145

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select newColumn = stuff(
  (
  select '' +[ATTR_VAL]
    from [NDC_ATTR]
    where item_id = 185836
      and field_id in (144, 225)
    order by 1 desc
  for xml path (''), type).value('.','varchar(max)')
  ,1,0,'')
```

or for more items:

```
select 
    t.item_id
  , newColumn = stuff(
  (
  select '' +[ATTR_VAL]
    from [NDC_ATTR] as i
    where i.item_id = t.item_id
      and i.field_id in (144, 225)
    order by 1 desc
  for xml path (''), type).value('.','varchar(max)')
  ,1,0,'')
  from [NDC_ATTR] as t
  where t.item_id in (...)
  group by t.item_id
```

optionally: add a delimeter: (notice the 0 changed to the length of the delimiter `';'` for the 3rd parameter of `stuff`)

```
select 
    t.item_id
  , newColumn = stuff(
  (
  select ';' +[ATTR_VAL]
    from [NDC_ATTR] as i
    where i.item_id = t.item_id
      and i.field_id in (144, 225)
    order by 1 desc
  for xml path (''), type).value('.','varchar(max)')
  ,1,1,'')
  from [NDC_ATTR] as t
  where t.item_id in (...)
  group by t.item_id
```

Comment: Thanks!, how would I modify the order? I can't get H400 to be second. How about TESTTEXT[H400]?

Comment: you can add `order by 1 desc` before `for xml path`